# Adding height: 100% to body in css

Tags: css

This is more of a curious question than it is needing help.

I'm working on solving a problem using percentage heights. I noticed that when I add height: 100% to the body tag, it stretches the body to the exact height of the window (which it should do). BUT, my content goes further than the total height of my body.

Is this a bad thing? Is it better to have my body set to 100% percent and let the content overflow, or to not set a height and let body "contain" all of the content?

Edit:

Nothing is absolutely positioned on the page. I have all of my floats cleared as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your body's height is set to 100% and none of the objects on your page are set to position: absolute your body should always adjust to its contents. It sounds like there may be some items on your page with special positioning.

Comment: I actually haven't positioned anything. I have heights set to certain containers though. Could the individual heights mess up the total height of the body?

Comment: There is a link to everything. I'm just seeing if there is a way for the individual spans to stretch to the height of the other spans, but that's when I came across the body - height problem.

Comment: It looks like everything is contained within the body in your example.  I do not see any overflow. Are you trying to maintain 50 pixels of white space on the bottom of the page? (using the margin-bottom)

Comment: @AndrewWhite I was at the start. The elements are all still contained, but when I Inspect Element, getting the dimensions of the body on shows that it goes down a certain length, not the full length of the body elements.

Comment: I guess that means just setting a min-height of 100 instead of height. I was just curious if anyone else had ever noticed the problem.